# open gl es2: fragment shader optimization

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

I have following simple fragment shader

```
 precision lowp float;
 uniform sampler2D u_texture_image;
 uniform sampler2D u_texture_mask;
 uniform lowp float u_blink;
 varying lowp vec2 v_texCoords_image;
 varying lowp vec2 v_texCoords_mask;
 varying lowp float v_shadow;
 void main() {
     lowp vec4 color= vec4(texture2D(u_texture_image, v_texCoords_image));
     lowp vec4 mask_color= vec4(texture2D(u_texture_mask, v_texCoords_mask));
     //masking image
     color = vec4(color.xyz,mask_color.a);
     //blink
     color =mix(color,vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,mask_color.a),u_blink);
     //check if its a shadow
     color=mix(color, mask_color*0.3, v_shadow);
     gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

I draw with this code 4400 polygons and get 25 fps(~40ms between onDrawFrame calls).This is not enough since this is not whole scene.
Can I somehow optimize this code?My target fps is 30.
Also I wonder are there some profiling tools for fragment shader code?

ADD:How do I call fragment shader

```
private void drawPieces() {
    //set my shader
    piecesProgram.useProgram();
    //set uniforms
    piecesProgram.setUniforms(MVPMatrix, textureImageId, textureMaskId,new PointF(2f,2f),0f);
    //load my vertcices with glVertexAttribPointer
    piecesMesh.bindPieceData(piecesProgram,false);
    //draw it with glDrawElements
    piecesMesh.drawPieces(false);
    piecesMesh.disableAttributes(piecesProgram);

}
```

Comment: Try not to allocate heap memory (new PointF(...)) in code you want to go fast. Goes for any programming language, any platform, any day.

Comment: A common way of testing if it is the fragment shader draining performance is to set a 2x2 viewport. Do it, see what happens, and tell your results.

Answer (score 0):

This shader does not look that complex.

What hardware are you using? 
Are you recompiling this shader every time you use it?
How are you calling this shader?

Apple has written a nice article about GLSL best prectices
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html

Comment: Added drawing code.I compile and link my program once within onSurfaceCreated.I think the problem is not in complexity of the shader, problem is in overal draw area(about 1.5 of the screen area)

BTW: is there way to post code in the comment?

Comment: I test on samsung galaxy tab a6

Comment: Your code does not look bad. 

You can use android GPU profiler to look if the GPU is indeed the bottleneck. You might take a look at this page.
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/dev-options-rendering.html